# fetch each name & id from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I'm getting an array of objects and I want to fetch the id & name from the array but it should not be done with foreach or any other loop. Here is my array

```
[{  companyId : "5cc6ca1b280cdf1522d1a3a4",     
    email : "abc+103@gmail.com",    
    firstName : "test",     
    inviteAccepted : false,
    lastName : "test",  
    _id : "5d512444955d441dfc52f640"     
 }, {   
    companyId : "5cc6ca1b280cdf1522d1a3a4",     
    email : "abc+104@gmail.com",    
    firstName : "test",     
    inviteAccepted : false,     
    lastName : "test", 
    _id : "5d528778e741722391d1fdd3"     
}]
```

I have tried

```
var IdArray = users.map(function (el:any) { 
           return {
                    _id:el._id, 
                    sourceName:el.firstName+el.lastName
           }; 
    });
```

But it shows sourceName as undefined
I want my result to be like this

```
[{  sourceName : "test test",       
    _id : "5d512444955d441dfc52f640"     
  }, {  
    sourceName : "test test",       
    _id : "5d528778e741722391d1fdd3"     
}]
```

Comment: Why do you have `sourceName` at all, if it's not in your desired output? I don't understand